# pfsense DHCP lease remember time settings?

Tags: dhcp, pfsense

pfSense remembers DHCP leases for a quite long time, which is good use on a LAN where the same machines request IP numbers frequently and have a chance to always get the same leases. However on an open guest Wifi this could cause the leases to clog up the lease list with IP numbers that never get assigned again.

Is there a way to limit the time a lease is removed and thrown into the available pool again? I have setup a network with 4096 IP numbers for my guest Wifi which should last a while when I have around 200 guests/day, but in order to keep the list clean, I'd like to drop leases after lets say 24h not used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change the DHCP lease duration.
It is a standard option in all DHCP servers.

In pfsense you'll find related settings under the Services / DHCP server page, in the "other options" part:

[image]

You'll have to change `Default lease time`and `Maximum lease time`settings.

Comment: Thanks, I have overseen that. I just wondered why there are leases in the list that are several days old. Probably just the list